# SQL - How Can I Order By Count From Other Table

Tags: sql

Hey stackoverflow community,

I know this question was asked before, but i don't understand the answerts so i cant use it for my own project. It would be amazing if someone could help me please.

I'm creating an little private url shortener and i want to order my urls by the views count. I setup my database like

- **Table:** urls: *id, user_id, alias, url, title, created*
- **Table:** views:
  *id, user_id, alias, visitor_ip, created*

If someone clicks a short link i ask for the stored date (user_id) for that url and add a row to views with the user_id and the alias so i know what link was clicked and what user has created this url. How can i get the urls order by rows in views with the same alias?

Something like this but with correct syntax

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE user_id = {ANYUSER} ORDER BY COUNT(alias) FROM views
```

Thanks for reading and i hope someone can help me. :)

**EDIT** because of some questions in comments.

Sorry for the missunderstanding. I have 3 tables users, urls, views. If someone registers he gets an auto incrementing user_id. If this user creates a short url it adds a row to urls with (user_id, alias, title) alias is a random generated string example: example.com/ **dHeJk** now if somone visits that url i first ask for the user_id that belongs to that alias (**dHeJk**) and store it in a variable after that i add a row to views with the data (user_id, alias) user_id = {the stored user} and alias = **dHeJk**. Now i want to list the urls in the users dashboard orderd by most viewed. Mosted views gets defined by how much rows are in the table views with that alias **dHeJk**

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your code is only selecting one `alias`, so it is unclear what you want to order.

Comment: agreed with @GordonLinoff, what's the point of  order by?

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. I have 3 tables users, urls, views. If someone registers he gets an auto incrementing user_id. If this user creates a short url it adds a row to urls with (user_id, alias, title) alias is a random generated string example: example.com/ **dHeJk** now if somone visits that url i first ask for the user_id that belongs to that alias (**dHeJk**) and store it in a variable after that i add a row to views with the data (user_id, alias) user_id = {the stored user} and alias = **dHeJk**. Now i want to list the urls in the users dashboard orderd by most viewed.

Comment: Mosted views gets defined by how much rows are in the table views with that alias **dHeJk**

Comment: I am sorry but still the question isn't very clear to me. Can you put some sample data to all 3 tables and show us what you expect in output based on that? Use sqlfiddle.com to create table statements so we can see them. Also mention your database

Answer (score 1):

You can join a query against your view table.

```
SELECT u.*, v.view_count
FROM urls u 
LEFT OUTTER JOIN  (SELECT user_id, count(*) view_count FROM views GROUP BY user_id) v on u.user_id = v.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = {ANYUSER} AND u.alias = {ANYALIAS}
ORDER BY v.view_count
```

I think part of your problem is your table/relationship design. You tables are related by the alias(derived from your original query) and the user_id. Provided that alias and user_id are the same in both tables, it would make more sense to establish PK/FK relationship as shown below whereas urls primary key is the foreign key in teh views table. [image]

Comment: If you're doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN v, you probably want to select ISNULL(v.view_count, 0) so you don't get NULLs in your result.

Comment: I would also add *WHERE user_id = {ANYUSER} * to the sub-query to limit the results. Something I forgot to do...

Comment: Final result: SELECT u.*, isnull(v.view_count) as view_count
FROM urls u 
LEFT OUTTER JOIN  (SELECT user_id, count(*) view_count FROM views WHERE user_id = {ANYUSER} GROUP BY user_id) v on u.user_id = v.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = {ANYUSER} AND u.alias = {ANYALIAS}
ORDER BY v.view_count

Comment: hmm. this does not work for me but i dont know why :(

Comment: Post your complete query. This should work. At the very least, include the error message. In your other comment you've mentioned MySQL. The query above is for MS Server. You'd have to come up with equivalent by changing the syntax. Left Outter Join is Microsoft's thing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is MS SQL, could you do something like this?

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.col2, a.col3 
FROM (SELECT user_id, col2, col3, (SELECT COUNT(@ANYALIAS) FROM views) as aliasCount
     WHERE user_id = @ANYUSER ORDER BY aliasCount) a
```

Comment: Sorry but i use mysql and with PDO Statements in php